How many ways do to make 4 ordered digits from 1 to 9?
How to make four-digits that are ordered from smaller number to a bigger number (left to right and vice versa) out of $1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9$. For instance: $1234$ and $4321$, $1236$ and $6321$, $2789$ and $9872$ and so on. This is a multiple-choice question with answers:
A) $120$
B) $144$
C) $156$
D) $220$
E) $252$
The attempt I made was too horrible to be shown. Anyway, here's what I've done so far:

As you can see there the first attempt of mine, I was making filling slots by considering the number of the digits and I use the multiplication rule.
The second attempt was by listing one by one and looking for the pattern and add them all. I got $110$. However, those two attempts seem off and I'm sure I missed loads of numbers. Please help me. I'm stuck.

If I understand well, you can choose any group of 4 distinct digits, and once you have this gtoup of 4 digits (example 1,5,4,8), you have 2 ways to dispose it (1,4,5,8 or 8,5,4,1) ; iif it is correct, this way of describing the process is a magic hint : how many subsets of 4 distinct digits can we build with 9 digits.

Think about how to create such a number/list. If I gave you its digits, could you find the number back? If not, how many numbers could you create with such a list of digits?

This is a common question with the typical reaction: can you count numbers like $0123$ or not? (and what about $2222$? Is that also well ordered or not?) :-)

@Lourrran Is it $2^9$, I was thinking of the $2^n$ formula for a number of subsets of a given set. Sorry, I can't think of anything...

To create such a number, you need to

select its four distinct digits in $\{1,\dots,9\}$,
decide if you want to place them in ascending or descending order.

Therefore, there are $\displaystyle\binom{9}{4}\times 2=126\times 2=252\text{ possibilities.}$

Generalization: following the same method, one can show that  there are $2\binom{n}{k}$ striclty monotonic words of length $n$ on an ordered alphabet of size $k<n$.

Thank you very much, it was embarrassing that I didn't see this problem as a combination thing. Anyway, the "times 2", is it for "descending" and "ascending"?

Exactly, the example @Lourran gave in its comment was, at step 1. select the subset ${1,4,5,8}$, and at step 2, you'll have two choices, ascending is $1458$ and descending is $8541$.

Combination, it is a complex word : you choose a digit (9 choices), then you choose another digit (8 choices), then another digit (7 choices), then another digit (6 choices), so intermediate result is $9\times 8 \times 7 \times 6$. But (1,2,3,4) or (1,3,4,2) or(4,1,3,2) ... it is same result, so we need to divide by something ... So even if you don't remember the word 'combination', you can MANUALLY find the result.
